# Angular, click through array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a variable that is set to an array index, and I want to try and loop through it on click. I have it initially set like:

```
 $scope.calenderState = ["day","week","month","year"];
 $scope.mod2m4 = $scope.calenderState[0];
```

and a click function connected that sends `mod2m4` like:

```
 ng-click ="changeCal(mod2m4)"
```

So right now it would send "day". Every time I click it, I want it to increment to the next item, (so week) unless its year, then back to day. How do I handle this scenario?

Edit: 
I am able to solve it like so, but I'm wondering if there is a bit more of an elegant solution?

```
var ind = _.indexOf($scope.calenderState, current);
if(ind == 3){
    $scope.mod2m4 = $scope.calenderState[0];
}else{
    $scope.mod2m4 = $scope.calenderState[ind + 1];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind the order of the array:

```
$scope.calenderState.push($scope.calenderState.shift());
$scope.mod2m4 = $scope.calenderState[0];
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe try storing just the index as a scope variable, then abstract the increment operation into a function (to deal with wrapping around)

```
$scope.index = 0
$scope.increment = function() {
  $scope.index += 1;
  if ($scope.index > 3) {
    $scope.index = 0;
  }
}
```

Then in your view if you want to display the value you can use the following expression:

```
<p>{{calendarState[index]}}</p>
```